# remove directories that do not contain media files

Tags: regex, bash, find

I am trying to make a script to delete folders that does not contain media files. The code below works but also deletes empty directories and the media could be in a sub directory of that empty folder so I do not want it deleted.

```
find /mnt/movies -type d '!' -exec /bin/sh -c 'ls -1 "{}"|egrep -i -q "^*\.(avi|mp4|mkv|srt)$"' ';' -exec /bin/rm -rv {} +
```

Example:

```
tree /mnt/movies/
/mnt/movies/
├── test1
│   └── 1.mp4
└── test2
    └── random.txt
find /mnt/movies -type d '!' -exec /bin/sh -c 'ls -1 "{}"|egrep -i -q "^*\.(avi|mp4|mkv|srt)$"' ';' -print
/mnt/movies
/mnt/movies/test2
```

Above would delete `/mnt/movies` so would delete everything.

Answer (score 0):

First, erase all the files you don't need anymore

```
 find /mnt/movies -type f ! -name '*.mp4' ! -name '*.avi' ! -name '*.mkv' -exec rm -v {} \;
```

You are left with some empty directories, and some directories containing media files. Now, pretend to remove all directories:

```
find /mnt/movies -type d -exec rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty -v {} \;
```

This will skip directories which are not empty, i.e. have media files.

If you don_t have Gnu rmdir (say, because you are on the Mac), use rmdir without any options, but redirect `2>/dev/null`, to avoid the error messages about non-empty directories.